# Why CardStyleInterpolators does not smooth on android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Transitions are smooth and smooth on IOS, but when pressing the back button on Android, there is stuttering like this.

[image]

```
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  CardStyleInterpolators,
} from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName={"Lorem"}
    screenOptions={{
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forFadeFromBottomAndroid,
    }}
  >
```